# In scala.swing, how do I remove a component from a Container?

Tags: swing, scala, scala-swing

In scala.swing, I can add a component to a container like so:

```
new Frame {
  contents += label
}
```

but sometimes I'd like to clear the contents of a container and replace them with new components. Based on the docs, I *should* be able to do:

```
frame.contents.remove(0)
```

or

```
frame.contents.clear
```

but neither of those compile ("clear/remove is not a member of Seq[scala.swing.Component]").

How can I resolve this?  Also, it seems that I can't call `frame.contents += blah` after intialization. If this is so, how do I add a new component to a Container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're talking about `Frame` specifically, you can only add one item, so use the method

```
def contents_= (c: Component) : Unit
```

and you should be good.  Try this out in the REPL (one line at a time so you can see what's going on):

```
import scala.swing._
val f = new Frame { contents = new Label("Hi") }
f.visible = true
f.contents = new Label("Hey there")
```

If you're using something that is intended to have multiple items like a `BoxPanel`, `contents` is a `Buffer` so you can add to it and remove from it:

```
val bp = new BoxPanel(Orientation.Vertical)
val (label1,label2) = (new Label("Hi"), new Label("there"))
bp.contents += label1
bp.contents += label2
f.contents = bp    // Now you see "Hi" "there" stacked
bp.contents -= label1
f.pack             // "Hi" disappears--need pack not repaint to fix layout
bp.contents += label1
f.pack             // "Hi" is back, but at the end
```

If you have something else like a `Component` that you're extending, it is your job to override `contents` with a buffer or have some other way of modifying it (or inherit from `SequentialContainer` as J-16 said).

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0):

`contents` in `Container` was a `Seq[]`;
you need a `SequentialContainer` for that remove method.